# Is there a way to create a "pop up" event creation in a calendar using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I am creating a calendar so members of different teams can create events based on what team they are on. I need it to work somewhat like Google Calendar. So when you click on the date, a "create event" pop up window will come up. The only thing in the pop up would be the title of the event, time, description, and the color that is assigned to that team.

There's got to be a way to do this in jQuery, but I've looked all over the jQueryUI website, and I can't seem to find anything.

Below is the HTML layout that I have created for the calendar.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
     <html> 
      <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>eTeam Leader Calendar</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    </head> 
    <body> 
     <div id="cal"> 
        <div class="header"> 
            <span class="left button" id="prev"> &lang; </span> 
            <span class="left hook"></span> 
            <span class="month-year" id="label"> January 2017 </span> 
            <span class="right hook"></span> 
            <span class="right button" id="next"> &rang; </span>

        </div> 
        <table id="days"> 
        <td>sun</td> 
        <td>mon</td> 
        <td>tue</td> 
        <td>wed</td> 
        <td>thu</td> 
        <td>fri</td> 
        <td>sat</td>

    </table> 
    <div id="cal-frame"> 
        <table class="curr"> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr><td class="today">1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td class="nil"></td><td class="nil"></td><td class="nil"></td><td class="nil"></td></tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>

    </div> 
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body { 
    background: #e0e0e0; 
} 

#cal { 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
    margin:50px auto; 
    font: 13px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvatica, Arial, san-serif; 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

#cal .header { 
    cursor:default; 
    background: #FFF800; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF800, #FFF800); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF800), to(#FFF800)); 
    height: 34px; 
    position: relative; 
    color:#000000; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-shadow:0px -1px 0 #87260C; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
} 
#cal .header span { 
    display:inline-block; 
    line-height:34px; 
}

#cal .header .hook { 
    width: 9px; 
    height: 28px; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom:60%; 

} 
.right.hook { 
    right:15%; 
} 
.left.hook { 
    left: 15%; 
}

#cal .header .button { 
    width:24px; 
    text-align:center; 
    position:absolute; 
} 
#cal .header .left.button { 
    left:0; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    border-right:1px solid #000000; 
} 
#cal .header .right.button { 
    right:0; 
    top:0; 
    border-left:1px solid #000000; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
} 
#cal .header .button:hover { 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#ffffff)); 
}

#cal .header .month-year { 
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center; 
}

#cal table { 
    background:#fff; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    width:100%;

} 
#cal td { 
    color:#2b2b2b; 
    width:30px; 
    height:90px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    text-align:center; 
    border:1px solid #e6e6e6; 
    cursor:default; 

} 
#cal #days td { 
    line-height: 26px; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-size:90%; 
    color:#9e9e9e; 
} 
#cal #days td:not(:last-child) { 
    border-right:1px solid #fff; 
}

#cal #cal-frame td.today { 
    background:#d3d3d3; 
    color:black; 
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset; 
} 
#cal #cal-frame td:not(.nil):hover { 
    color:#000000; 
    text-shadow: #FFF800 0px -1px; 
    background:#FFF800; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF800), to(#FFF800)); 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px; 
}

#cal #cal-frame td span { 
    font-size:80%; 
    position:relative; 
} 
#cal #cal-frame td span:first-child { 
    bottom:5px; 
} 
#cal #cal-frame td span:last-child { 
    top:5px; 
}

#cal #cal-frame table.curr { 
    float:left;      
} 
#cal #cal-frame table.temp { 
    position:absolute; 
}
```

Comment: In general, what you should look to do is create some identifier on each cell so that you know what Day the user clicked on, then read & pass that value into a function to set the date for the event the user is creating. For example, each clickable Day cell could have a defined class (say "Day") along with some data-* attribute (say 20170101 = Jan 1, 2017). You'd then create a click handler for Day cells (`$('.Day').click(function() { //get data-* attribute with date});` & grab the date of the clicked cell to know where to create the event.

Comment: There is no built in method for this. You can bind to `click` and launch a dialog or tooltip. As @Stevangelista mentions, you can add `data` attributes or `id` to help create the form in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided an example of your JavaScript or any of your current attempts, I would advise reviewing the following example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Here is an example of how you could use it: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8vj8qzm4/

**HTML Added**

```
<div id="newEvent" title="New Event">
  <form>
    <label for="newEventTitle">Event Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="newEventTitle" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="newEventTime">Event Time</label>
    <input type="text" id="newEventTime" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="newEventDesc">Event Description</label>
    <input type="text" id="newEventDesc" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="newEventTeam">Team</label>
    <input type="text" id="newEventTeam" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS Added**

```
#newEvent label,
#newEvent input {
  display: block;
}

#newEvent input.text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: .4em;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  function checkLength(o, min, max) {
    if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  function addEvent(d) {
    var valid = true;
    $("#newEvent input").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    valid = valid && checkLength($("#newEventTitle"), 3, 80);
    if (valid) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "newEvent.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          eventName: $("#newEventTitle").val(),
          eventDate: d,
          eventTime: $("#newEventTime").val(),
          eventDesc: $("#newEventDesc").val(),
          eventColor: $("#newEventTeam").val()
        },
        success: function(resp) {
          // Response may contain an Event ID that could be added to the calendar
          $(".selected-day").removeClass("selected-day");
        }
      });
    }
    return valid;
  }

  var $popup = $("#newEvent").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Create Event": function() {
        addEvent($(".selected-day").html());
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      $("#newEvent form")[0].reset();
      $("#newEvent form input").removeClass("ui-state-error");
      $(this).dialog("option", "title", "New Event");
    }
  });

  $("#newEvent form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addUser($(".selected-day").html());
  });

  $("#cal-frame td").click(function(e) {
    var day = parseInt($(this).html());
    $(this).addClass("selected-day");
    var month = $("#cal .month-year").html();
    var title = $popup.dialog("option", "title") + " for " + day + month;
    $popup.dialog("option", "title", title);
    $popup.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

This is only tested as far as I could. It's not clear how you want to save this event, I assumed to a PHP Script that would enter it into a database. It's not clear how you want to represent the even on the calendar layout. So there is still lots for you to do.

This is only one way to do this, there are others out there.

Comment: Styled to be a little more "google" like: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8vj8qzm4/4/